# possible to download the repository from Gitlab to your local machine?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to download code from gitlab to my local machine. Is it possible to download the respository from Gitlab to your local machine?

Comment: Use git to clone or use the download button at the repo?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can download from the download button on repository:

[image: Download button]

You can also clone the repository using command:

```
git clone [repository-url]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download directly from gitlab. Look for this icon
[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OFan.png) in repository you want to download.

Answer (score 0):

**YES** using **gitclone** through GitBash we can easily download the repository from Gitlab to your local machine.